# Angular.js input[type='date'] validation not fired if partly entered (e.g. only day)

Tags: angularjs, html, date

I have `input[type='date']` with no further validation rules.

Validation is not fired in the case when only **part of a date is entered** (say, the day and month). So when you have '**01/02/YYYY**' it's been taken for empty value and `$error.date is not changed`, so the validation message is missing.
If you first enter any valid date and then remove its part (say, the year) `$error.date` is updated and a validation message shows up.

Does anybody have any idea how to fire validation on a partly entered date?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-date-input-directive-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="dateInputExample">
  <script>
   angular.module('dateInputExample', [])
     .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.example = {
         value: ''
       };
     }]);
  </script>
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
    <label for="exampleInput">Pick a date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value" />
    <div role="alert">
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.date">
         Not a valid date!</span>
     </div>
     <tt>value = {{example.value | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}</tt><br/>
     <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
     <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
     <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
     <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Julia, how you solve this.

Comment: @Ajay2707, actually I had to wait till Angular fixed the bug in one of the next versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was fixed in the next versions of Angular (upgraded from 1.4.3 to 1.8.2):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-date-input-directive-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="dateInputExample">
  <script>
   angular.module('dateInputExample', [])
     .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.example = {
         value: ''
       };
     }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
   <label for="exampleInput">Pick a date:</label>
   <input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value" />
   <div role="alert">
     <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.date">
         Not a valid date!</span>
    </div>
    <tt>value = {{example.value | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```